# IIS unable to resolve Image url

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have saved my website in the wwwroot folder. when i am running it through Visaul Studio 2008 it s running absolutely fine with path

```
          http://localhost:3840/GettingUserId/default.aspx
```

but through IIS it is unable to resolve the images URL , not even the links to other pages r working (Parser Error). The path is

```
          http://bhukrk106154d/GettingUserId/default.aspx
```

I am using IIS 5.0.
Is there any IIS setting that I am missing out.I have simply copied the same website folder inside the   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot folder

Comment: How about some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen parser errors becasue the website is trying to use an old framework version.

Go to the default website properties in inetmgr -> go to asp.net tab -> make sure that asp.net version 2.0 is selected.

If you can post the error message it will be usefull too.